# Burninate request: [fetchmail]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Can we burninate the [fetchmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fetchmail) tag? It currently has 21 questions, none of which are on-topic.

All of those questions may be on-topic on either Super User or Server Fault.

Comment: I didn't know [Samuel L Jackson used fetchmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055614/whats-in-your-muttrc)

Comment: I have gone through all of them and cast some CVs. Let's see what the CV queue will do.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with this request. From Wikipedia's definition:

> Fetchmail is an open source software utility for POSIX-compliant operating systems which is used to retrieve e-mail from a remote POP3, IMAP, ETRN or ODMR mail server to the user's local system. It was developed from the popclient program, written by Carl Harris.

That being said, this tag isn't even on-topic for this site - it's about general computing, not programming.

I say we burninate it.